# using custom font in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, custom-font

I need to use custom font in xaml (c#). The font is not installed on the computer.

If the font is in the application  installed folder,then i can use it even if it is not installed (/Fonts/New12.ttf#New12)

My problem is that the custom font is been created on the local computer and can't be in the installed folder.

The problem is that i can't copy the ttf file to the application  installed folder , and i don't know how to use custom font that is not on the application installed folder

Is anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Add the font to your project, change its **Build Action** to **Content**. Then just reference it inline or as part of a Style or BasedOn value like;

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Fonts/New12.ttf#New12" Text="Check out my awesome font!" />
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: When you add the font file to your project,it will be in the installed folder.The problem is when the font is been created on the fly.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean then, by creating your font on the fly?

Comment: I'm creating the ttf file in my app.But you can think about it like i'm downloading the ttf file

Comment: So it's not a file available during build?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution,

For the `FontFamily` value you can write

`"ms-appdata:///local/MyFont.ttf#FontName"`

(where local is `ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder`)