# Fonts added with AddFontResourceEx are not working in GDI+

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, gdi+

AddFontResourceEx returns 1 for each font, but the fonts are not accesible in GDI+ (Tested with VS2015 and Windows 10, also on Windows 2008 R2 Server).

If I install the fonts manually with Windows Fonts Explorer everything works ok.
It seems that GDI+ cannot find the fonts added with AddFontResourceEx or AddFontResource, any idea how can I get this working?

I use CodeJock Library which uses GDI+ fonts for rendering XAML graphics, so I cannot control how to fonts are created.

```
int n = 0;
CPathW pw;

pw.Combine(theApp.m_strMyAppFolder, _T("Roboto-Light.ttf"));
n =AddFontResourceEx(pw, FR_PRIVATE, nullptr);

pw.Combine(theApp.m_strMyAppFolder, _T("Roboto-Thin.ttf"));
AddFontResourceEx(pw, FR_PRIVATE, nullptr);

pw.Combine(theApp.m_strMyAppFolder, _T("Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
AddFontResourceEx(pw, FR_PRIVATE, nullptr);

pw.Combine(theApp.m_strMyAppFolder, _T("Ubuntu-R.ttf"));
AddFontResourceEx(pw, FR_PRIVATE, nullptr);

pw.Combine(theApp.m_strMyAppFolder, _T("Ubuntu-L.ttf"));
AddFontResourceEx(pw, FR_PRIVATE, nullptr);

::SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the fonts in the same process? _"This function allows a process to use fonts without allowing other processes access to the fonts."_

Comment: Yes it's the same process and no DLLs

Comment: The question presumes that AddFontResourceEx() has a bug.  It does not have a bug.  Don't ignore the return value, error handling is not optional. And don't ignore the odds that the problem is located in the code that uses this library.  Those odds are always very, very high in SO questions.

Comment: It returns 1 for each font, that is not an error, it's the number of installed fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GDI+ you need to use class [`PrivateFontCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534491(v=vs.85).aspx) which solves a similar purpose as AddFontResourceEx() with FR_PRIVATE.

There is already an example at the documentation for [PrivateFontCollection::AddFontFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534992(v=vs.85).aspx) so I'm just commenting on that.

The example adds fonts from the Windows Fonts folder to the private font collection which is pointless because these fonts are available anyway.
You already load the fonts from the application folder in your AddFontResourceEx() example so you can use the same paths for `PrivateFontCollection::AddFontFile()`.

Another thing to note is that the `PrivateFontCollection` object should stay around as long as the application is running and should not be recreated everytime one wants to draw text with these fonts. A good place would be a member variable in the application class. This should be obvious but the example makes it appear as if you have to recreate the `PrivateFontCollection` everytime. This would be a major performance hit.

**Edit:**

> I use CodeJock Library which uses GDI+ fonts for rendering XAML
> graphics

The `PrivateFontCollection` is propably not so easy to use in this context, as it doesn't make the fonts globally available in your application, but has to be used as constructor argument of `Font`. But you wrote that you don't control how the fonts are created by CodeJock.

Maybe CodeJock supports private fonts directly in the XAML, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12752811/7571258) which is for C# but maybe works for CodeJock too.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to specify the font file in XAML, but Codejock library does not support this. The good part is that almost any codejock classes can be overided and modified, so there is still some hope. So are you saying that PrivateFontCollection does not make the font available globally in my application?

Comment: _PrivateFontCollection does not make the font available globally in my application_ ... that's right. You have to create font objects like this to use font from PrivateFontCollection: `Font myFont(familyName, 16, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel, &privateFontCollection)` (see example at documentation for PrivateFontCollection::AddFontFile).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find another solution to create the fonts for Codejock XAML TextBox.